# Is "I'm going with you" similar to "I'm coming with you"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

For my English listening practice I am using "Audio Books". Most of them are in British English (UK audio books). In a conversation, John said, ***"I'm going with you"*** (to a music festival).

Usually we use ***"I'm coming with you"***, but here John used *"I'm **going** with you"*. Is this okay?

Answer (score 1):

One way to correctly understand the difference in coming and going is to understand the underlying verbs that define them. These are borrowed from the dictionary. I strongly suggest you follow and stick to one type of english because a mixture of UK-English and US-English can cause a lot of sentences to lose their meaning(personal experience).

**coming**(*adj*)-> **come,came**(*verb*)  = Reach a destination by movement or Move toward something or somebody or approach something or somebody

**going**(*adj*) -> **go, went,gone, goes**(*verb*)  =  change location or proceed (also used metaphorically) or Move away from a place into another direction

You should notice the small differnce that come is usually used in the second line of conversation if it is a statement. If it is used in the first line of the conversation, it is usually followed by a question. 
example: You do not start a conversation with someone saying "I am coming to the movies." You say, I am going and someone will ask Can I come along ? or vice versa. 
One has to look in to the broader picture to get the meaning.
I hope this can help.

cheers pal !

Comment: Even in the example @Maulik explained, the usage of coming is not in the first line of the conversation !

Comment: so, which one you think is improper?

Comment: I do not think they are improper but I think there should be in a specific order while making a conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both mean the same. However, I've heard 'I'm coming with you' *more in Indian English.*

Another option is 'That makes two of us'. Say-

> I am going to a music festival ~ *That makes two of us!*

---

I remember something related from my hostel days. And there 'I'm *going*' cannot work. In an incidence, when I was going to a movie and started walking out of my room, my roommate asked me that where I am going. "Movie!", I answered while getting down the stairs and he hurriedly shouted, "Wait, I'm **coming**!"

Comment: "*I am **coming** with you*" would be used mostly when considering the destination, and "*I am **going** with you*" -- when considering the journey.

Comment: But then the journey, in almost all cases, ends in the destination! @VictorBazarov

Comment: And that's why what we mostly hear is "I'm coming with you".